# Unet spawning my 2 players in same location

Tags: spawning, unet

I have min and max number of players set to 2. I have 2 empty game objects in my scene with Network Start Position scripts attached. I have "Round Robin" as the player spawn method in my Network Manager. And yet my players often spawn on top of each other. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you added `NetworkStartPosition` component to the spawnable objects?

Comment: Yes... I'm at a loss...

Comment: Oh wait... to the spawning objects?  Doesn't that script only go on the start position objects themselves??

Comment: [This will probably help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239336/spawn-player-at-specific-location-with-unet)

Comment: I guess... maybe I have to control the spawning myself, but my game is so simple I can't imagine the unet presets can't handle it.  Only 2 spawn positions, round robin.  It must be something simple I'm missing.